# What is the unit for memory values in XDebug traces?

Tags: php, xdebug

What is the unit for memory values in Xdebug traces? bytes?

For instance, I have these lines:

```
TRACE START [2011-11-30 13:11:18]
0.2122    2618704  +489048           -> require_once(...) ...:8
...
0.4147    6847864      +64             -> strtr(string(34), array(128)) ...:21
```

So, does 6847864 = 6.5MB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same as `memory_get_usage` (and basicly any other notification about memory in PHP):

> Returns the amount of memory, in **bytes**, that's currently being
>   allocated to your PHP script.